# how to stop snapshot being taken while deleting tables or keyspaces in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

While dropping a table or keyspace, Cassandra takes a backup of all sstables. How to avoid this as I am dropping the table, I no longer  need  the table? The same snapshot is taken while dropping a keyspace also. Which is easier in terms of work done by Cassandra, a keyspace drop or table drop?

Answer (score 1):

To disable the snapshot, set `auto_snapshot: true` in cassandra.yaml and restart your instances. The snapshot is there to guard against accidental deletion.

To do a keyspace drop, all the tables need to be dropped too.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the keyspaces doesn't delete the data.

After dropping the keyspaces, to free the memory, you need to go into the data subdirectory and "rm -rf [the individual keyspaces]".